# Managing tables in MS Word by Java application

Tags: java, velocity, docx, xdocreport

I am using `XDocReport` and `Velocity` to fill simple tables in `docx` files. Now, I would like to create table with merged fields.
[image: wish]

Is it possible to do this in `XDocReport`? If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need, you wish to set a mergefield and replace this mergefield with a table?

If it that, you can use [HTML text styling](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainHTMLTextStyling). You design your docx template like this :

```
${htmlTable}
```

You mark that **htmlTable** field uses **HTML syntax** :

```
FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();
metadata.addFieldAsTextStyling("htmlTable", SyntaxKind.Html);
```

You put in the context, the HTML table :

```
context.put("htmlTable", "<table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table>");
```

But today, it's very basic, you cannot manage border, width, height, etc for HTML table. See issue [302](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=302)